# Was this Starscream's only time as sole leader of the Decepticons?

Tags: transformers, character-development

In *Transformers: The Movie* (1986), Starscream boldly throws a badly wounded Megatron out of Astrotrain into deep space, and seizes the Decepticon leadership.

[image: Starscream in a crown]

Sadly he is murdered at his own coronation by a vengeful Galvatron, but it is still a unique moment in Starscream's character history.

Apart from this one occasion,  has Starscream ever, in **any** continuity, been sole leader of the Decepticons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You describe the state of the Deception forces in  of most of the first seasons of *[Transformers: Animated](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transformers_Animated_(cartoon))* and *[Transformers: Prime](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transformers:_Prime_(cartoon))*

In *Transformers: Animated*'s three-part pilot "Transform and Roll Out", Megatron is the recipient of Starscream's treachery, and apparently destroyed.

> Megatron attacks the Autobot ship and tries to retrieve the Allspark,
> but when an explosive planted on Megatron by the treacherous
> Starscream detonates, the ship crashes on Earth. The Autobots go into
> stasis to survive the crash, while the scattered remains of Megatron
> are discovered by a human scientist named Isaac Sumdac.

-- Wikipedia, *[Transformers: Animated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Animated)*.

From the viewpoint of the Decepticon forces on Earth, Starscream is in command from the end of the pilot up until S1E16, [Megatron Rising, Part 2](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Megatron_Rising_-_Part_2).

In *Transformers: Prime*,  Megatron ends the pilot comatose in lunar orbit. Starscream subsequently takes command of the earthly Decepticon forces, which appear to be all that are surviving.

> Season One opens with Cliffjumper being murdered by Starscream, who
> leads the Decepticons during 'Lord' Megatron's absence. Following
> Megatron's return, he uses Cliffjumper's corpse as a test subject for
> Dark Energon, which he intends to use to create an undead army from
> Cybertron’s fallen warriors. The plan fails when the Autobots destroy
> Megatron’s Space Bridge, leaving him in a comatose state floating
> through the empty space, and allowing the treacherous Starscream to
> claim leadership of the Decepticons once more.

--Wikipedia: *[Transformers Prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Prime)*

Starscream leads the Decepticons from the end of the pilot, until the end of S1E14, "[Out of His Head](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Out_of_His_Head)."

Comment: ,+1 Oh wow, "Lord Starscream"? This is what we all wanted! AMAZING!

Comment: @EleventhDoctor Yeah, these are just the two situations I'm most familiar with. If I'm not mistaken, there's an arc in one of the comic continuities where Starscream becomes the legitimately-selected head of state of Cybertron, but I'm not sufficiently familiar  with the comics to give further reference.

Answer (score 5):

In [Transport to Oblivion](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transport_to_Oblivion_(episode)),

> Megatron is knocked into the active Space Bridge and is presumed
> destroyed. Starscream assumes command and orders a retreat.
>
> STARSCREAM: "Megatron is dead! I am your leader now! Follow ME!"

For a short while, though. Megatron emerges apparently unscathed at the Cybertron end of the Space Bridge, and vows vengeance against the Autobots.

[youtube](https://youtu.be/07yYfhX69Ac?t=1262)

Comment: +1 Great answer, thank you! I loved the youtube video!